# F ratio, degrees of freedom, calculate probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I found the variance estimate based on mean, which was 15.68

Also found variance estimate based on variance, which was 3.4

The F-ratio is (15.68/3.4) = 4.61

Degrees of freedom for the numerator is 2 and 21 for the denominator (2/21)

With the given information how would I find the probability of observing a difference in sample means?

Comment: What is the variance estimate based on the variance?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb : I suspect what is meant is that the "variance estimate based on mean" is the between-group sum of squares and the "variance estimate based on variance" is the within-group sum of squares. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:**

You need to look in printed tables of the F distribution or use software.

For a one-sided test (to see if sample variance 15.68 is *significantly* larger than 3.4) at the 5% level, based on the degrees of freedom you mention, the critical value is 3.47. Because 4.61 > 3.47 you would reject at the 5% leval.

The 95th percentile of F(2,21) is 3.47. In R statistical software `qf(.95, 2, 21)` returns 3.4668. Most statistical software packages and some statistical calculators do such computations. ('Quantile' is sometimes called 'inverse CDF': In Minitab the command/subcommand `MTB > InvCDF .95; SUBC> f 2 21` returns 
3.46680.)

If you prefer to use P-values you can use software (but not printed tables). In R the P-value for your test is found to be 0.022, as follows:

```
 1 - pf(4.61, 2, 21)
 ## 0.02188824
```

Selected percentiles (above the 50th) are given in some printed tables. Printed tables
often use a notation that mentions the 'right-tail' probabilities instead of the quantile. Thus you might see this value denoted as $F_{2,21;.05}$ in a table.